# Viewing data retrieved from core data stored in an NSArray

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have an iPad app where data is stored in `core data`. I have used the following code to retrieve the data from the Observations entity which appears to run without any problems and the count of observationList is correct.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Observations"];
NSError *error = nil;
observationList = [[NSArray alloc]init];
observationList = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

However when I try to access the data with the array - for example:

```
    NSLog(@"%@", [[observationList objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"obsDate"]);
```

It throws an error

```
reason: '-[Observations objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector
```

obsDate exists in core data. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Should probably also be using `valueForKey:`

Comment: Agree with Wain..checkout this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSManagedObject` does not implement `objectForKey:`, you should be using `valueForKey:` instead. Your code compiles because the array returns an `id` so the compiler just has to trust that the method you're calling on it will exist at runtime.

Aside: this line is pointless

```
observationList = [[NSArray alloc]init];
```

Because you throw away that array instance on the next line.